# Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response], drop = drop, : argument is missing, with no default

Tags: boxplot

Error creating boxplot

```
 boxplot(Temperature~Quarter,
       data=temp_final,
       xlab="Quarter",
       ylab="Degrees C",)
```

I am trying to plot Quarter 1-4 on the x axis and temperature on y axis